# Docker unable to delete images

Tags: docker

I have some docker images on my machine (macOS) which I am trying to delete. When I run

```
docker rmi 4873874c08ef
```

I get the following error :

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 4873874c08ef (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 1a0a55a6a684
```

But when I search for the list of containers using `docker ps -a`, I see no containers. Trying to force delete also returns the same error. How do I delete the images here?

```
docker rmi -f 4873874c08ef
```

Comment: Have you tried `docker kill 1a0a55a6a684`?

Comment: I'd try restarting docker

Comment: I tried docker kill to kill the process and then delete the image, but still get the same error. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling docker, but the same issue

Comment: did u try to stop the container and then delete images?

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete container first.
You can list all container by: `docker ls -a`.
Probably container 1a0a55a6a684 will be on the list.
Delete it by: `docker rm 1a0a55a6a684` and then `docker rmi 4873874c08ef`